# Oracle sql: ORA-01830 when date calculation happens

Tags: sql, oracle, compiler-errors

I want to perform following oracle SQL query

```
SELECT t1.Technology, count(t1.trax_id) as "Current number of items", to_char(to_date(max(round((SYSDATE - t1.time_event) * 24 * 60 * 60)),'sssss'),'hh24:mi:ss') as "max_ages"
from dm_procmon t1
group by t1.Technology;
```

The problem is the date substration formula.

> I susbtract 2 dates from each other. This gives me a decimal value
>   (like 0,00855605). I want the value back to be a date value.  So I
>   converted this first to a Number (Decimal > Number)  and than to a
>   char (Number > Char) Finally from a char to date (Char > Date).

But when I perform the action I receive
Error report -

> SQL Error: ORA-01830: Datumnotatieafbeelding eindigt voordat de gehele
>   invoerstring is geconverteerd.
>   01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"

What do I do wrong?

Comment: please describe, what result do you expect and what is the content of `time_event`

Comment: I susbtract 2 dates from each other. This gives me a decimal value (like 0,00855605). I want back to a date value. So I converted this first to a Number and than to a char, than char to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you try to convert to_date(%number of seconds%, 'sssss'), that is the problem. just use `TO_CHAR(MAX(TO_DATE('20000101','yyyymmdd')+(SYSDATE - t1.time_event)),'hh24:mi:ss')`; this will function correctly for intervals < 1day

Comment: when you should overflow the 1 day interval, use own function instead of `TO_CHAR` that performs rounding down and multiplication, e.g. 0,00855605 : 0d, *24=0,2053452 : 0h, *60=12,320712 : 12m, *60=19,24272 : 19s (0d0h12m19s) and returns this result...

Comment: Normally that won't happen. A id stays normally half a day in the system. But I keep it on my mind.

Comment: or with a simple adjustment you could have the correct behavior for intervals < 31days: 1. date `20001130`, 2. format `'dd:hh24:mi:ss'`

Answer (score 0):

here is a general solution without any limitations on maximum interval size:

```
select Technology, cnt as "Current number of items", FLOOR(x) || ':' || TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20000101','yyyymmdd')+(x - FLOOR(x)),'hh24:mi:ss') as "max_ages"
from
    (select t1.Technology, COUNT(t1.trax_id) cnt, MAX(SYSDATE - t1.time_event) x
    from dm_procmon t1
    group by t1.Technology);
```

`FLOOR(x)` returns the days and the rest (`x - FLOOR(x)`) is added to a constant date and transformed to hours, minutes and seconds

Answer (score 0):

The following will give a `DAY TO SECOND INTERVAL` for all dates within about 68 years of one another:

```
SELECT t1.technology, COUNT(t1.trax_id) AS "Current number of items"
     , NUMTODSINTERVAL(ROUND((SYSDATE - MIN(t1.time_event) * 24 * 60 * 60), 'SECOND') AS "max_ages"
  FROM dm_procmon t1
 GROUP BY t1.technology;
```

Note that rather that using `MAX(SYSDATE - time)`, I used `SYSDATE-MIN(time)` (logically the same). The advantage of using this instead of `TO_CHAR()` is that you can then use the value returned in `DATE`/`INTERVAL` arithmetic.